What is the importance of bilinear functions?
Dimension plays a important role in mathematics. We are convinced that linear functions are worthy of consideration, since dimension is actually a measure that characterizes the degree of linear independence. Also, it makes sense that the all linear functions is the very important data for a linear space. Then we may raise a natural question what is the importance of  bilinear functions for linear spaces?
In a sense of calculus, we seem to be able to find some traces of the importance of  bilinear functions, as shown in the following.
Let $\mathbb{R}$ be real numbers. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Then we can use derivative calculations of $f(x,y)$ to deal with some geometric problems. For any vector $\mathbf{v}=k\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + l\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in the tangent space $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb{R}^2$, by the sense of directional derivative, we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{v}}(x,y)=k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+l\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y).$$
Of course, this is a bilinear operator,  and the thing of calculus is certainly very important.  However, I believe there is more evidence to convince me that bilinear is of great importance. So,  more things are left to you to write in the following. Thank you very much for your answer.

Inner product spaces come to mind. Over a real field the inner product is bilinear, over a complex field the inner product is conjugate linear.

You are correct,  Thank you for comments. I mean there is another story in my example. We regarded the derivative as a more general concept, i. e., bilinear function, which actually has advanced reason here.  This perhaps arise for us to do calculus on manifolds in the further development.   But I do not know the reason of taking inner product as a bilinear.   Any way,  this is just what actually comes to mind. Thank you ！

A bilinear form $g$ gives you a canonical linear map $v \mapsto g(v, \cdot)$ from a vector space to its dual. If $g$ is non-degenerate, this map is an isomorphism.

These comments provide an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answers as an answer.

An overall principle is the following: The laws of physics, as well as geometric properties of a space should not depend on the coordinates used for the space. If you assume the space is flat and therefore a vector space, then one of the consequences is that everything has to be independent of the basis of a vector space. It is easy to show that any geometrically invariant function on $V$ has to be affine (linear plus constant) and any geometrically invariant function of $k$ vectors has to be multilinear. plus constant  Basic examples are inner product and determinant. But there are many more.

This is just an expansion of my comment, as suggested by @MartinBranderburg. My answer is restricted to applications in linear algebra and geometry.
Given a vector space $V,$ and its (algebraic) dual space $V^*,$ there is not a canonical way to identify vectors in $V$ with elements of $V^*.$ Of course, if you are given a basis $B = (e_i)_{i \in I}$ of $V,$ then you can define a system $B^* = (\phi^i)_{i \in I}$ in $V^*$ by the equation $$\phi^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j$$
for $i, j \in I.$
It is always the case that $B^*$ is linearly independent, and if $V$ is finite-dimensional then $B^*$ is the dual basis. In this way, you have a one-to-one linear map from $V$ to $V^*$ given by $e_i \mapsto \phi^i$ for each $i \in I.$ If $V$ is finite-dimensional, this map is an isomorphism.
Let us suppose that we want to fix a linear map $f : V \to V^*.$ It is often a good idea to add the structure necessary for our purposes, but no more. In this case, working with vector spaces with basis like $(V, B)$ is overkill: two different basis might result in the same map $f.$
If we are given such a linear map $f,$ then we can always define a bilinear function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb K$ by $$\langle v, w \rangle = f(v)(w).$$
And vice versa, given $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ we can recover $f$ by the above equation, read from right to left. This shows that being given a bilinear form is exactly the same thing as being given a linear map $V \to V^*,$ so a bilinear form is exactly the additional structure that we are looking for.

Let us restrict ourselves to finite-dimensional vector spaces for the rest of the answer. Given a basis $B,$ we can represent the bilinear form by a matrix $G$ such that
$$ \langle v, w \rangle = v_B^T G w_B, $$
where $v_B, w_B$ are the vectors $v, w$ written in the base $B$ in column notation. This provides an interpretation of certain matrix concepts. The matrix $G$ is:

Invertible iff $f$ is an isomorphism, i.e., $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is non-degenerate.
Symmetric iff $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is symmetric.

And so on.

Another non-canonical choice on an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ is the choice of a volume form, i.e., you cannot do $|\det(v_1|\cdots|v_n)|$ because you don't have a way to measure lengths and angles. Given a non-degenerate bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle,$ you can define
$$|\det(v_1|\cdots|v_n)|^2 = \left|\det\pmatrix{\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle & \cdots & \langle v_1, v_n \rangle \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \langle v_n, v_1 \rangle & \cdots & \langle v_n, v_n \rangle}\right|.$$
The determinant on the right is of a matrix with scalar entries (the Gram matrix), so it is well-defined. It is also non-zero whenever $v_1, \dots, v_n$ form a basis: in this case, it's just the matrix $G$ given above. When the bilinear form is positive-definite (an inner product), then the gram determinant is positive and the absolute value may be dropped. This makes it possible to define, for example, the area of a surface in $3d$-space, using only the inner product of tangent vectors.
Note that $|\det(v_1|\cdots|v_n)|$ such defined has all the properties that you would expect of a determinant, except for the sign. In order to have a well-defined signed volume you also need to specify an orientation.
A final remark is that an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ allows interchanging covariance and contravariance in tensors. In the simplest case, this allows the identification of the differential of a function $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ with its gradient $\nabla F \in \mathbb R^n$ at each point, in such a way that $\nabla F$ is basis-independent (it only depends on the inner product). I hope this provides enough motivation for the identification between a space and its dual.

OK, I can well get your idea. Thank you very much！

The important overarching concept is that of a multilinear map, which is the generalization of a bilinear map to more than two input vectors. I'm going to present multiple important applications.
Geometry: products
The well known products in vector geometry are all bilinear. The dot product (generalizable towards general inner products) is a symmetric bilinear form and it allows us to calculate lengths. The cross product is an antisymmetric bilinear map that yields a vector orthogonal to both inputs. And we can combine them to the so called triple product: The product $u\cdot(v\times w)$ is trilinear and gives us the signed volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $u,v,w$.
Linear algebra: the determinant
Let $B$ be a base of a vector space $V$ and $f:V\to V$ be linear. Then the determinant of $f$ can be seen as a multilinear form on the images of $B$ under $f$. By the way, in this view it is also a generalization of the triple product mentioned before: The triple product of the images of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ under a linear map is that map's determinant.
Calculus: Higher order derivatives
The derivative of a function between normed vector spaces is a linear map. Its second derivative is a bilinear map (represented by the Hessian matrix in the special case where it is a bilinear form because the original function has scalar output). Its third derivative is a trilinear map, etc. In general, a suitably differentiable function can be approximated by a sum
$$f(x+h)\approx f(x)+L_1(h)+\frac{1}{2!}L_2(h,h)+\frac{1}{3!}L_3(h,h,h)+\dots,$$
where $L_k$ is a $k$-linear map, the $k$-th derivative of $f$ at $x$.
Differential geometry: differential forms
Differential forms are the objects we can integrate (over a curve, an area, a volume,...) in differential geometry. A differential form $\omega$ can be described as a sum of wedge products $\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy\wedge\dots$ of more primitive differential forms. And the wedge product is, you guessed it, multilinear.
Applied math: a lot
Anytime a quantity of interest depends linearly on multiple inputs, it's multilinear in those inputs. For instance, from a physicists perspective, momentum is a bilinear function of mass and velocity, since $p=mv$. Or more complicated, kinetic energy is a bilinear form of momentum and velocity: $E_{\mathrm{kin}}=\frac12 \vec p\cdot\vec v$ (since $p=mv$ and $E=\frac12 mv^2$). But also, the volume of a parallelepiped is multilinear in its edges represented as vectors. Production cost is a bilinear form in the number of required materials and their asscioated cost. Covariance of two random variables is bilinear in the varibales. And many more.

Thank you very much for your kind answer. I am more convinced for the importance of bilinear functions, since I got the multiple important applications in your answer.

Community Wiki because the question is very open and others might have more insight than I do.
Anyway, here is my first thought, trying to keep your geometric motivation. Consider the map $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that maps
\begin{equation}
(\binom{v_1}{v_2},\binom{w_1}{w_2}) \to \det
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 & w_1 \\
v_2 & w_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
This is bilinear, and geometrically it tells you the (signed) volume of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors in the argument. Note that the result is zero if and only if the two vectors are linearly dependent. Bilinearity now tells you that scaling one side of the parallelogram by a constant factor $c$ changes the resulting volume by exactly that constant factor $c$.
This extends (as a multilinear map) to volumes of parallelotopes in higher-dimensional space.
Other examples of bilinear functions include the well known scalar product in an Euclidian linear space: $f: E\times E\to{\Bbb R}$ defined by $f(\vec x, \vec y) = \vec x\cdot \vec y$, or the vectorial product in a linear space of finite or countable dimension: $f: E\times E\to E$ defined with $f(\vec x,\vec y) = \vec{x}\times \vec y$

I really think that you post a very comfortable answer.  Sorry, due to some network reasons, I don't have the habit of using Wiki. Anyway, in fact, I can use Wiki in sometimes, although it is a way  factor through math.stackexchange.   Thank you very much!
